# How to access localhost on android over wifi wampserver?

Tags: android, apache, networking, localhost

With Wampserver and Windows, I want to access localhost on android over wifi.

The ip of my computer is `192.168.0.20`. Sam wifi network.

I added `Require ip 192.168.0` on `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.39\conf\extra\http-vhosts.conf` *(Same problem if I added Require all granted')* :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
    Require ip 192.168.0
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I try to access it from my phone android (Same Wifi network), I have this error :

> This site can't be reached
>
> 192.168.0.20 took too long to respond.
>
> Try:
>
> Checking the connection
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to map the localhost to your computer ip Address , you need to get the ip address from the ipconfig cmd command and you need to check your firewall